# Не работает форма для регистрации

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Есть форма для регистрации, но про нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.
Код формы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="ajax_framework.js" language="javascript"></script>

<!-- Show Message for AJAX response -->
<div id="login_response"></div>

<!-- При отправке формы вызывается функция login() из ajax_framework.js -->
<form action="javascript:login()" method="post">
<input name="emailLogin" type="text" id="emailLogin" value=""/>
<input name="pswLogin" type="password" id="pswLogin" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax_framework.php:

```
    function createObject() {
var request_type;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;
}

var http = createObject();


/* ----------------------- */
/*      LOGIN              */
/* ----------------------- */
/* Переменная nocache содержит случайное число, добавляемое в запрос
   для предотвращения кеширования браузером запроса */
var nocache = 0;
function login() {
 // Отображаем соощение в области ID ajax_response
 document.getElementById('login_response').innerHTML = "Loading..."
    // Проверяем, что все поля не пустые. Используем encodeURI() для кодирования недопустимых символов в запросе.
var email = encodeURI(document.getElementById('emailLogin').value);
var psw = encodeURI(document.getElementById('pswLogin').value);
 // Получаем случайное число
nocache = Math.random();
 // Pass the login variables like URL variable
http.open('get', 'login.php?email='+email+'&psw='+psw+'&nocache = '+nocache);
http.onreadystatechange = loginReply;
http.send(null);
}
function loginReply() {
if(http.readyState == 4){ 
var response = http.responseText;
 if(response == '0'){
// if login fails
  document.getElementById('login_response').innerHTML = 'Login failed! Verify user and password';
// else if login is ok show a message: "Welcome + the user name".
  } else {
document.getElementById('login_response').innerHTML = 'Welcome'+response;
  }
}
```

login.php :

```
    <?php include('config.php');

// Verify if user exists for login
if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['psw'])){

$email = $_GET['email'];
$psw = $_GET['psw'];

/*$getUser_sql = 'SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email="'. $email . '" AND psw = "' . $psw . '"';
$getUser  = mysql_query($getUser_sql);
$getUser_result =  mysql_fetch_assoc($getUser);
$getUser_RecordCount = mysql_num_rows($getUser);*/
$proof_email = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' ");
$getUser_result =  mysql_fetch_assoc($proof_email);
if($getUser_RecordCount = 1){ echo '0';} else { echo "Good";}
}
?>
```

config.php :

```
    <?php
 $link = mysqli_connect( 
            'localhost',  /* Хост, к которому мы подключаемся */ 
            'root',       /* Имя пользователя */ 
            '',   /* Используемый пароль */ 
            'hentai'); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Код в файле `ajax_framework.js` синтаксически неверный - в нем отсутствует завершающий `}`. Проверьте сообщения в консоли разработчика Вашего браузера - в нем вы увидете `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.

Проверить js-код, на корректность, можно линтером, например [тут](https://www.jslint.com/)